# incorporating javascript library into code

Tags: java, html, css

I have html and javascript that grabs a file and parses it and places chunks of the file in a textbox. However, the file has ANSI codes for colors. I want the textbox to display these colors as well. I have found [ANSI4J](https://github.com/PavelKastornyy/ansi4j) but I don't know how to incorporate it into my code. There is a readme file and it posts the following:

```
var palette = new XtermPalette256();
AttributeConfig config = new DefaultTextAttributeConfig.Builder()
        .defaultForegroundColor(0x000000)
        .defaultBackgroundColor(0xffffff)
        .fontFamilies(List.of("Arial", "'Times New Roman', Times, serif"))
        .extraColorsEnabled(true)
        .palette16(palette)
        .palette256(palette)
        .build();

//Now we need context that will keep attributes.
AttributeContext context = new DefaultAttributeContext(List.of(config));

//Now we create a function processor.
var processor = new DefaultCssFunctionProcessor.Builder()
        .resolvers(new DefaultTextAttributeResolver())
        .generators(new JavaFxCssGenerator())
        .build();
...
//To generate CSS declarations we need to process function fragments. Currently only SGR functions are supported
Fragment fragment = ... ;
if (fragment.getType() == FragmentType.FUNCTION) {
    FunctionFragment functionFragment = (FunctionFragment) fragment;
    if (functionFragment.getFunction() == ControlSequenceFunction.SGR_SELECT_GRAPHIC_RENDITION) {
        List<String> declarations = processor.process(functionFragment, context);
        var style = String.join(";", declarations);
        ...
    }

}
```

but I don't know what to do with this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your question is tagged JavaScript, but your code looks like Java, and the library is for Java.

Comment: ANSI4J is for coloring text in a TTY console.  HTML textareas don't support styling, but there are HTML WYSIWYG editors that might preserve styles in pasted text.

Comment: Thank you Barmar and Mike Samuel I will look into WYSIWYG